# dynamic label using timer in c#

Tags: c#, timer, label

I need a label that text will be change after a timer one tick.For example, timer 1st tick label will show "1 program running", in 2nd tick label will show "2 program running" in 3rd tick label will show "3 program running" and so on.
I am new in programming.Any help will be great appriciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Did you try handling timer tick event with sth like that:

```
int counter = 1;
private void timer1_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    label1.Text = counter + " program running";
    label1.Refresh();   //not necessarily
    counter++;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Well, you'll need to maintain some state. To be honest, the *simplest* way of doing that is to capture a variable in a lambda expression:

```
int count = 0;
timer.Tick += (sender, args) => {
    count++;
    label.Text = string.Format("{0} {1} running", count,
                               count == 1 ? "program" : "programs");
};
```

Alternatively, you can create a new class to maintain that state:

```
internal class ProgramCounterTimerHandler
{
    private int count = 0;
    private readonly Label label;

    internal ProgramCounterTimerHandler(Label label)
    {
        this.label = label;
    }

    internal void ShowProgramCount(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        count++;
        label.Text = string.Format("{0} {1} running", count,
                                   count == 1 ? "program" : "programs");
    }
}

Then you can use:

timer.Tick += new ProgramCounterTimerHandler(label).ShowProgramCount;
```

Alternatively, if you're happy having an instance variable within your class, you can keep track of the count that way.

Comment: Like the answer, but shouldn't `count == 1` be `count >= 1`

Comment: @Windle: Nope - we only want "program" to be singular when count is 1.